# how to send custom data in opnet simulator fom one node to the other?

Tags: packet, opnet

I wrote a program that hides wave audio files inside bitmap images and I would like to apply it in the opnet simulator.
I would like to send the image from one node to another but i don't know how to send any sort of data from a node to another.
if possible I would like any hints or a tutorial for this part.

Answer (score 1):

You may have two options:

1. Use the SITL (System In The Loop). SITL will make you connect a real device(PC) to Modeler(OPNET).
2. Use a *Value Vector Packet* in the Package Package API.